# Is $Z_t = U\sin(2\pi t) + V\cos(2\pi t)$ is strictly stationary?

Tags: time-series, covariance, stationarity, cumulative-distribution-function

Let $Z_t = U\sin(2\pi t) + V\cos(2\pi t)$, where $U$ and $V$ are independent random variables each with mean 0 and variance 1. Is $Z_t$ strictly stationary?

**Answer**: I have proven that $Z_t$ is covariance stationary (i.e., constant mean, constant variance, and covariance is free of $t$).

I know that if a process is strictly stationary, then it is covariance stationary. However, is there a way to use the fact that $Z_t$ is covariance stationary to help with proving strictly stationary? Do I need to find the CDF of $Z_t$ in order to establish strict stationarity?

Comment: The answer depends on what "$t$" means.  If, for instance (as suggested by your application of the [tag:time-series] tag) $t$ is taken to be an *integer,* then $Z_t=V$ and this obviously is a strictly stationary time series process.  But if $t$ is parameterized by a larger set, such as all real numbers, then let $U$ and $V$ be Rademacher variables (giving equal chances to the values $\pm 1$) and conclude $Z_t$ cannot be stationary.

Comment: $t$ can be any integer!

Comment: Then this is a trivial question because $\sin(2\pi t)=0$ and $\cos(2\pi t)=1$ for all integral $t.$

Comment: This helps answer my question!